# Connect WCF client without config file (but via code)?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, basichttpbinding

I know that this question is already been asked (in some kind of form) but I'm new to this and can't make it work.
Problem: need to create a .NET dll (c#) which I need to call from PowerBuilder (via COM) --> the dll will handle the SOAP client call to a webservice.

Not much experience in .NET but managed to 'talk' to a (for example) public web service. But the problem is that I can't use a config-file (otherwise error that endpoint is not found).

Please, can anyone help me out with this (example code for this maybe)?

This is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GlobalWeatherSoap"
          contract="SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoap" name="GlobalWeatherSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx"
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="GlobalWeatherSoap12"
          contract="SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoap" name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I added a 'service reference' via the WSDL-file and call the webservice like this (for example):

```
SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient("GlobalWeatherSoap");
string strCities = client.GetCitiesByCountry("Belgium");
```

Can anyone tell me please how I can achieve the same as what I did but without the config-file?

I think I need to go via 'BasicHttpBinding()' but don't how I get to referencing the 'SrvRefWeather'-object in my example.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Really...

Thanks,
Marc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this (simple) example work:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx");

SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new SrvRefWeather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient(binding, address);
string strCities = client.GetCitiesByCountry("Belgium");
```

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the "contract-tag in the CONFIG-file?
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGBww.png)

I didn't use it in my example here but it works...
So I was wondering where (and if) it is used?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need the contract: to connect to a service you need ABC = address, binding, contract.  Probably your proxy `GlobalWeatherSoapClient` has a `ServiceContractAttribute` that defines the contract (ConfigurationName property, or defaults to the Type name).

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for your reply (and info). I'll (try to) look further into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question, but personally I would always use XML configuration, as it's much easier to read and understand than creating everything in code.

If you don't want / can't have an external configuration file, you could have the configuration XML included in your assembly, e.g. as a string constant or as an embedded resource.  You can then use the [ConfigurationChannelFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575311(v=vs.110).aspx) class to create your client channel from this configuration data.

If you want to explore this approach and don't understand how to use `ConfigurationChannelFactory` to achieve this, post a comment or another question.

Comment: Thanks Joe.
I don't mind having an external configuration file but I can't have an external configuration file (it's PowerBuilder that will be calling this dll via COM and it's the calling exe which should have the CONFIG-file which does not work here).

Comment: I'll look certainly into the solution regarding the embedded resource. Looks interesting!